# Where is a Scala profile for SonarQube?

Tags: scala, sonarqube

Is there basic ruleset/quality profile for SonarQube for the Scala language?

I couldn't find any and it's hard to imagine that everyone starts with an empty ruleset.

Answer (score 6):

I have build a plugin for running Scalastyle on SonarQube. It comes with the default Scalastyle Quality profile and you can create or customise quality profiles.

[github.com/emrehan/sonar-scalastyle](https://github.com/emrehan/sonar-scalastyle)

Comment: https://github.com/NCR-CoDE/sonar-scalastyle is a more updated repo of the same code.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there's a plugin under development http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Scala+Plugin but it's been inactive for a while :)
I assume that this plugin (when released) will be shipped with predefined set of rules.

Comment: Can Scalastyle be integrated with Sonar? (yes this is a new Question but i assume you can tell me if its worth opening another one.)

Comment: I assume that as CheckStyle was integrated with Java plugin the same applies here ;-)

Comment: If my findings are correct there currently is no way of having Scalastyle work with Sonarcube because the CheckStyle plugin there is not recognizing/using the Scalastyle output even though technically SCalastyle does output in Checkstyle format.